# How to execute DELETE and SELECT statements as one query with JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa

I would like to get SELECT statement result before DELETE statement is executed, but they both use the same temporary table created at the beginning and I cannot use *query.getResultList()* and *query.executeUpdate()* at the same time. Is there any other way?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE xyzToDelete SELECT xyz FROM ...
----
SELECT * FROM xyzToDelete
----
DELETE FROM <using xyzToDelete>
```

```java
private String deleteXYZ;
----
<here I put sql file content into this string>
----
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(deleteXYZ);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: *"How to execute DELETE and SELECT statements as one query with JPA?"* Short answer not possible, `DELETE` and `SELECT` follow differenct code paths in MySQL, the best you can do is starting a `TRANSACTION`

Comment: What do you want it's possible and it's called  "SQL Injection",  I'm 100% agreed  with @ Raymond Nijland comment

Comment: *"I would like to get SELECT statement result before DELETE statement is executed"*  Well execute the `SELECT` first in the code and then the `DELETE` the java code will "block"  (main/current thread) and wait for results first. ...

Comment: *"What do you want it's possible and it's called "SQL Injection","* Not sure why you are mentioning "SQL injection" here @EduardoEljaiek but indeed you have to handle `createNativeQuery(..)`  with care when you use it..

Comment: Maybe if you share what the end goal is, we can help a little more.  Are you saying you would like to re-use the select statement to drive the delete request?   Or are in general, are you trying to share/reuse a temporary table?

Comment: Exactly, I want to share a temporary table @VAIJason. I thought about splitting SELECT and DELETE statements into two files, and executing them sequentially (CREATE and SELECT in 1st query, DELETE and DROP in 2nd query) but I don't want to risk that after creating temporary table some error happens and 2nd query would not execute, letting temporary table exist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with ACID. A transaction will rollback if not completed.
You should split your SELECT & DELETE into two transactions.

your best bet would be:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(CREATE TABLE xyzToDelete SELECT xyz FROM SELECT * FROM xyzToDelete);
List<String> results = query.getResultlist();
Query query2 = em.createNativeQuery(DELETE FROM xyzToDelete);
List<String> changes = query.executeUpdate();
```